# Unable to run uBlock Origin core in NodeJS: "snfe.useLists is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

After installing the ubo-core package (`npm install @gorhill/ubo-core`) and importing it in my project I am unable to use an instance of the StaticNetFilteringEngine.

My code (`ublock.mjs`):

```
async function read(path) {
    return readFileSync(resolve(__dirname, path), 'utf8');
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const { StaticNetFilteringEngine } = await import('@gorhill/ubo-core');
    const snfe = StaticNetFilteringEngine.create();
    await snfe.useLists([
      read('./lists/badware.txt')
                    .then(raw => ({ name: 'badware', raw })),
    ]);

    // Not blocked
    if (snfe.matchRequest({
      originURL: 'https://www.bloomberg.com/',
      url: 'https://www.bloomberg.com/tophat/assets/v2.6.1/that.css',
      type: 'stylesheet'
    }) !== 0) {
      console.log(snfe.toLogData());
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
})();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
"snfe.useLists" is not a function
```

Any thoughts on why this functon is not recognised? I am running it in Node.js (`node ublock.mjs`) using NPM 8.12.1 and Node.js 14.16.0. I am following the example in the [ubo-core documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gorhill/ubo-core).

Answer (score 0):

`StaticNetFilteringEngine.create()` is `async`, so you need to `await` it:

```
const snfe = await StaticNetFilteringEngine.create();
```